# Query LDAP server using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, lotus-domino

I'm trying to run a query on LDAP, but I get exception UnauthorizedAccessException @ new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser). (see code below)

I don't understand why the application doesn't have access to run this query as when I run 
ldapsearch command line tool it works fine.

```
        using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "machineName"))
        {
            using(UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
            {
                using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
                {
                    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
                    {
                        var user = (UserPrincipal)found;
                        Console.WriteLine(user.GivenName + " " + user.Surname +  " " + user.EmailAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you use `ldapsearch` from the command line, are you running the command line instance as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, But my account is part of the administrators group so I expected to work. Either way, I ran Visual Studio under Administrator, also tried running like Debug>Debug As Administrator... still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21203191) on how to collect debug data for LDAP on the Domino server side.  I would suggest using the LDAPDEBUG=7 setting right from the get-go, and comparing the console log output on the server for your ldapsearch query and your program's query.

What you probably need to pay attention to is the authentication during the bind operation.  You haven't mentioned whether you passed any authentication info in the ldapsearch command line (-D and -w arguments), and you haven't said anything about SSO -- and I'm not even sure if Domino LDAP participates in any SSO.  The data logged on the server should help clarify what (if any) identity your query is using for binding.  Normal settings on the Domino Directory would protect against anonymous queries, and I think it also restricts the attributes available when a user without Editor rights (or above) queries other user accounts.

If you do not have administrative rights for the server, or a test server on which you can duplicate the problem, you will have to coordinate with the actual admins. You don't want to leave the LDAPDEBUG setting turned on longer than necessary.

Comment: I don't pass in any credentials. Here is the command that I'm running ldapsearch -L -h hostname "objectClass=*" givenname sn mail . How can I achieve same command in C#? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the relevant classes in C#.  I still very strongly encourage you to use the LDAPDEBUG setting on the server.  It is the best way to see what your code is really sending to the server.  Understanding the difference between what your code sends, versus what ldapsearch sends, is the key to solving this problem.

Comment: Thank you Richard. What you said is the proper way of debugging it, unfortunately I didn't had that luxury as I had to do the implementation asap.

Answer (score 0):

Please see code below:

```
        using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME"))
        {
            using(UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
            {
                using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
                {
                    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
                    {
                        var user = (UserPrincipal)found;
                        Console.WriteLine(user.GivenName + " " + user.Surname +  " " + user.EmailAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I do it like this it works fine, but I cannot specify the server name. Also not sure if it returns same results as the command line.

I tried using ValidateCredentials to check if the validation passes using my credential (using ContextType.Machine) but instead of returning true or false it throws the UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried accessing the domino server using a different method in .NET, unfortunately this one didn't worked either. (it thrown DirectoryServicesCOMException (A protocol error occurrred).

```
        // create your "base" - the ou "formeremployees"
        DirectoryEntry formerEmployeeOU = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://HOSTNAME");

        // create a searcher to find objects inside this container
        DirectorySearcher feSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(formerEmployeeOU);

        // define a standard ldap filter for what you search for - here "users"    
        feSearcher.Filter = "objectClass=*";

        // define the properties you want to have returned by the searcher
        feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
        feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
        feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        feSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

        // search and iterate over results
        foreach (SearchResult sr in feSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            //do something
        }

        return;
```

The quick solution for me is to run the ldapsearch command line tool.

```
        // Start the child process.
        Process p = new Process();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "ldapsearch";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-L -h hostname \"objectClass=*\" givenname sn mail";
        p.Start();
        // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
        // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
        // p.WaitForExit();
        // Read the output stream first and then wait.
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"output.txt", output);
        return;
```